# PHP DateTime equality

Tags: php, datetime

How can I compare if two DateTime objects have the same day,month and year?
The problem is they have different hours/min/seconds.

Comment: OK, no more close votes, please. OP has clarified the requirement for comparing two dates irregardless of time. Sorry for the oversight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no nice way of doing that with DateTime objects. So you'll have to do, lets say, not so nice things.

```
$nDate1 = clone $date1;
$nDate2 = clone $date2;

//We convert both to UTC to avoid any potential problems.
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$nDate1->setTimezone($utc);
$nDate2->setTimezone($utc);

//We get rid of the time, and just keep the date part.
$nDate1->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$nDate2->setTime(0, 0, 0);

if ($nDate1 == $nDate2) {
    //It's the same day
}
```

This will work, but like I said, it's not nice.

On a side note, recent experience tells me its always best to make sure both dates are on the same timezone, so I added the code for it just in case.

Comment: If I apply date_default_timezone_set('GMT') would this be enough instead of $nDate1->setTimezone ?

Comment: I believe so, as the question I had linked to just now does that.

Comment: No, if for example, the DateTime had been constructed with a string of the form '2020-04-23 20:30:20+0500' the default timezone would have no effect on it, and you'd have a problem.

Comment: Why isn't nice about this solution?

Comment: @erisco having to clone the objects and wiping them of the time part in order to compare them just strikes me as ugly, necesary, but ugly.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$date1->format('Ymd') == $date2->format('Ymd');
```

:wq

Answer (score -3):

```
if(date('dmY', $date1) == date('dmY', $date2))
```

You can put it in a function...

```
function compare_dates($date1, $date2){
  if(date('dmY', $date1) == date('dmY', $date2))
    return true ;

  return false ;
}
```

is most useful ;)

Comment: Date expects second parameter to be an integer so this doesn't work as $date1 and $date2 are DateTime objects. $date->getTimestamp() solves this problem.